# XML take the position of an element and at next usage go directly there

Tags: c#, xml, wikipedia

So i have a huge XML file ( wikipedia dump xml ) .

My school project requirement says that i should be able to do a really fast search on this xml file ( so no, not import it into an sql database )

so of course i want to create an indexer, that will display into a separate file ( probably xml ) something like this : [content to search]:[byte offset to the start of the xml node that contains the content]

My question is how can i take the position of the element, and how can I jump to that position in the xml in case it is required for a search ?

The project is in C#. Thank you in advance.

Later Edit : I am trying to work with XmlReader, but I am open for any other suggestions.

For the moment this is how I read my XML for a non-indexed search

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FileName);

while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.Name)
    {
        case "page":

            Boolean found = false;
            String title = "";
            String element = "<details>";
            readMore(reader, "title");
            title = reader.Value;

            if (title.Contains(word))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            readMore(reader, "text");
            String content = reader.Value;
            if (content.Contains(word) & !found)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            if (found)
            {
                element += "<summary>" + title + " (click)</summary>";
                element += content;
                element += "</details>";
                result.Add(element);
            }

            break;
    }
}
reader.Close();
if (result.Count == 0)
{
    result.Add("No results were found");
}
return result;

…

static void readMore(XmlReader reader, String name)
{
    while (reader.Name != name)
    {
        reader.Read();
    }
    reader.Read();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet and if so, can you post some of that code?

Comment: Do you have some guarantees about the XML structure of the portions of text being indexed? Text only, valid XML fragments, …

Comment: You really shouldn't build XML as a string, like you do. Use `XDocument` (or `XmlDocument`) or `XmlWriter`, if the resulting XML is also big.

Comment: I think you need to modify your index idea : don't index by 'byte' - index by node-number (so this is taking the idea from Julien Royer below : but don't use a DOM - build a stream processor (SAX in java - I'm not sure in C#) that doesn't hold the entire input document in memory. Perhaps you index could be based on a simplified 'XPATH' syntax something like : /root/title[0]/paragraph[5] [ to uniquely identify a node ] with a list of search keywords. (Or the reverse).

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be to use an intermediary binary format; but if you can't do that, and assuming that you use DOM, I don't see any solution but to store the position of the node in the DOM tree as a list of indexes.

Example in JavaScript (should be fairly the same in C#):

```
function getPosition(node) {
  var pos = [], i = 0;
  while (node != document.documentElement) {
    if (node.previousSibling) {
      ++i;
      node = node.previousSibling;
    } else {
      pos.unshift(i);
      i = 0;
      node = node.parentNode;
    }
  }

  return pos;
}

function getNode(pos) {
  var node = document.documentElement;
  for (var i = 0; i < pos.length; ++i) {
    node = node.childNodes[pos[i]];
  }

  return node;
}
```

Comment: but doesn't the DOM load the entire XML into the memory ? I can't afford that cause my test XML has like 1GB and the one that the application should run will be close to 40GB.

Comment: DOM is indeed not an option then…